# Execute parallel database access in ADO.Net C#

Tags: c#, asp.net, multithreading, ado.net, async-await

I'm working on asp.net application to display multiple widgets on dashboard. So I'm sending an ajax call to get all the required data to the dashboard widgets.

Inside the server method there are multiple  database calls to get relevant data for each widget from the database via stored procedures. Method content as follows;

```
List<DashboardItem> items = new List<DashboardItem>();
items.Add(GetUserList()); 
items.Add(GetNewsList()); 
items.Add(GetRecentlyViewedList()); 
items.Add(GetSentEmailsList()); 
.....
return items;
```

It seems this process is very slow due to the no of records in the database.

I'm trying to execute above code with Async database calls. It seems async database operations can improve this process. Can anyone help me to write async database operations? or any other suggestions to improve performance on database method calls?

Comment: https://dotnetcodr.com/2014/01/01/5-ways-to-start-a-task-in-net-c/

Comment: on your GetXXX use the Async versions of the database connector with the `await` keyword, then instead of returning `DashboardItem[]` return `Task<DashboardItem[]>`, then you can create a `List<Task<DashboardItem[]>>`, add the returnted Tasks from these functions, then do `await Task.WaitAll(theListOfTasks)` and finally use the `.Result` of each task stored in the list.

Comment: Instead of trying to execute queries in parallel, simply batch them all together. NHibernate allows batching, and EF can batch queries using extensions. Parallel execution helps only when you have to move a *lot* (think GB) of data data over multiple network cards. Otherwise you simply introduce more concurrency overhead and use way more connections than needed

Comment: @Gusman using blocking methods like `WaitAll` is a *bad* idea. The whole point is to reduce blocking. `await Task.WhenAll()` won't block.

Comment: @Aruna why are you trying to execute different queries in parallel? Do you really have a problem, or do you assume that you *may* have one? Using more connections than necessary *reduces* scalability and can probably lead to *greater* delays. In any case, slow database access means there is a problem with the data, not the access method

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos You're totally right, It's a mistake (WaitAll is not awaitable at all) I meant WhenAll.

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos actually for each and every widget there are sps to process data. So to get all the required widget data, i need to run all of them which introduced the slowness.

Comment: @Aruna no, that doesn't result in delays, unless the SPs are *not* well written. BTW there is no performance difference between a raw SQL query vs a stored procedure. What *does* result in delays is establishing multiple connections and the unnecessary roundtrips. You could batch all calls together and pay only for a *single* round trip.

Comment: Moreover, if you use Ajax and have multiple widgets, *why* are you loading all widget data in a single call? Have each widget load its own data. Add caching at the ASP.NET/IIS level so you *don't* have to reload the same data. Cache data like news etc that don't change frequently in memory, so you only load them once per hour

Comment: Even better, use a different controller per item type so you can control their caching individually, *and* result in a much cleaner URL

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos Thanks for detailed information.

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos,  In widgets there are links to load additional data which request data from the server again. If I load widgets individually, user has to wait until all the requests to be completed to view that additional data on already loaded widget. Am I doing something wrong there??

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos actually the widget data is frequently changing.

Answer (score 1):

You need to have your entry point marked as `Task` returning and you can then use `async` and `await` keywords. Also, the `GetUserList`, `GetNewsList`, `GetRecentlyViewedList` and `GetSentEmailsList` methods will also have to be `Task` returning such that you go `async` all the way -- (notice the naming convention of adding Async to the methods to indicate their nature).

```
public async Task GetDashboardItemsAsync()
{
    var getUserTask = GetUserListAsync();
    var getNewsTask = GetNewsListAsync();
    var getRecentlyViewedTask = GetRecentlyViewedListAsync();
    var getSentEmailsTask = GetSentEmailsListAsync();

    await Task.WhenAll(getUserTask,
                       getNewsTask,
                       getRecentlyViewedTask,
                       getSentEmailsTask);

    return new List<DashboardItem>
    {
        getUserTask.Result,
        getNewsTask.Result,
        getRecentlyViewedTask.Result,
        getSentEmailsTask.Result,
    };
}
```

Storing the tasks in a variable will allow you to access the `.Result` after they have all been materialized. The `Task.WhenAll` method takes an array of `Task` and it will continue once all of them have been completed.

With this approach you're basically saying start each task to fetch the dashboard data, once all asynchronous operations have *ran to completion*, then continue to returning the list of `DashboardItem` to the caller.

---

This is primarily addressing the calling code and how to handle the multiple tasks in a parallel manner. In order to start the fetch operations at the **ADO.NET** level that should be a different question. But there are a lot of `async` APIs on **ADO.NET** and **Entity Framework** too.